# mean based on condition from another column

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
Date               Value    Name
17/12/17 8:39:00   NAN      ME
17/12/17 8:39:00   20       DE
17/12/17 8:39:00   30       RP
17/12/17 8:40:00   33       ME
17/12/17 8:40:00   39       DE
17/12/17 8:40:00   5        RP
17/12/17 8:41:00   1        ME
17/12/17 8:41:00   2        DE
17/12/17 8:41:00   32       RP
17/12/17 8:42:00   4        ME
17/12/17 8:42:00   43       DE
17/12/17 8:42:00   45       RP
```

I want to calculate the average of `ME` when the value of `RP` is >=17.
Then , the average of `DE` when the value of `RP` is >=17.

So, I am not taking into consideration the values of `ME`, `DE` when the values of `RP` are <17.

I can't think how to combine this.
If I try to use `filter` and filter out the `RP` and select only `value >=17`, then I will loose the information for `ME` or `DE`.

So, for example, the average value of `ME` is (NAN + 1 + 4) / 2.
The average value of `DE` is (20 + 2 + 43) / 3.

Comment: For same conditions you want to calculate values of both `ME` and `DE` ? Can you update your post with expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah:yes, you are right,I have updated.

Comment: what about the value 33 in row 4 for `ME` ? Also how should the final dataframe look like?

Comment: @RonakShah:The value 33 is not counted because at the same timestamp, the RP has value less than 17 (5).I just want a simple value, the average.

Comment: but you only have values for `19/12/17` for `RP`, so what should happen to the rest of the days?

Comment: @mtoto:Sorry!Copy-paste mistake, I am updating.The dates are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is easier to use a wide format of your data. Thus first I use `spread` and then `filter` with your criterion and finally `summarize` to get the mean.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  spread(Name, Value) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("ME", "DE", "RP"), as.numeric)

df
#               Date DE  ME RP
# 1 17/12/17 8:39:00 20 NaN 30
# 2 17/12/17 8:40:00 39  33  5
# 3 17/12/17 8:41:00  2   1 32
# 4 17/12/17 8:42:00 43   4 45

df %>% 
  filter(RP >= 17) %>% 
  summarize(ME_mean = mean(ME), 
            DE_mean = mean(DE))

#   ME_mean  DE_mean
# 1     NaN 21.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %<>% filter(df$Date %in% df$Date[df$Name == "RP" &
                                       df$Value >= 17]) %>% group_by(Name)

mean_df <- summarize(df, means = mean(Value, na.rm = T))
```

`df$Date[df$Name == "RP" & df$Value >= 17]` returns all timestamps where RP is greather than 17. Then I filter the dataframe by these dates, group it by name and calculate the mean.

Result:

```
> mean_df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   Name    means
  <chr>    <dbl>
1    DE 21.66667
2    ME  2.50000
3    RP 35.66667
```

Inspired by @kath's anwer, I'd suggest converting the format of the dataframe by spreading it out

```
mean_df %<>% spread(Name, means)

> mean_df
# A tibble: 1 x 3
        DE    ME       RP
*    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 21.66667   2.5 35.66667
```

And you could drop the RP column if you don't need it

```
mean_df <- mean_df[ , !(names(mean_df) %in% "RP")]

> mean_df
# A tibble: 1 x 2
        DE    ME
     <dbl> <dbl>
1 21.66667   2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the help (upvoted).I just liked the other solution